# plug and play machine learning

Tags: c#, python, sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

What would be the easiest way to get started with machine learning?

I have a very practical application for it.

A few managers threw a **data warehouse** of "stuff" in my lap asking me to tell them what is **driving sales.**

The data includes:

```
sales by client (clients being doctors offices)
sales by doctor
products they bought
client demographics
all kinds of different date information
```

To summarize the data, it is basically the complete data of EVERY transaction the company conducted with all of their clients and detailed information for every transaction.

The data is all stored in sql server 2008.

**Question:** Are there any tools that already exist in c#/python that I can hook up to the database that will start analyzing trends/patterns/relationships?

**More specifically:**
How can I apply a machine learning algorithm using python or c# to my data in order to extract some kind of meaningful information?

Comment: I think you'll have to actually learn a little about machine learning before you can answer this question. As far as I know, we haven't invented the Oracle "gimme what I want" program yet. There are libraries, such as Weka, that you could use algorithms from. But if you don't know which algorithms to use and why you're using them, it's unlikely you'll get what you want. The easiest way to get started is to start reviewing some openly available courseware on it: https://www.coursera.org/course/ml

Comment: I read this a little while ago: http://www.heatonresearch.com/book/programming-neural-networks-cs-2.html and it was extremely helpful in understanding how all of this sort of thing works. There's a stock exchange example with full source code that shows patterns and predictions.

Comment: I really liked "Programming Collective Intelligence" (http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596529321.do). It is very broad and includes search, optimization, classification, and modeling techniques. It is in python and has a lot of real-world examples using data sets from fb, hotornot, finance, etc. that are pertinent the kind of modeling/feature analysis you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has a prediction / machine-learning API which is pretty awesome if you're more interested in the results than the understanding (although it will certainly be helpful to have some background so you can know things like if what you're trying to do even makes sense).

https://developers.google.com/prediction/

Comment: thank i am trying this right now. do you have experience with this?

Comment: looks like we are neighbors! i'm all in SD. UTC to be exact!

Comment: I haven't used it, but I've heard a lot of great things.

Comment: let me know when you try! very anxious for feedback

Comment: I would also like to know more...I couldn't find anything related to C# or databases...the examples seem to be solely e-mail/spam based for the most part.

Answer (score 1):

You get data mining tools bundled in SQL Server 2008. You should start by googling something like 'Introduction to data mining in SQL Server 2008' for practical examples.

Comment: cool! i didnt know this existed. seems like a very steep learning curve.

Comment: Yes there is a lot to learn but it's very powerful and I suggest that it's the quickest way to get to the result you need (and make yourself very employable)

Comment: great point! have you tried google prediction api? it's pretty amazing!

Comment: Wow. I'm just in the Google API's console and I'm already hooked.

Comment: It's all cool butI won't actually be exploring it until I have a pet project time to implement it!

Comment: did you get some project yet??

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure where to start in approaching this question.  First, the issue here is not "machine learning".  There is no software out there that can take in a bunch of database tables and answer a question such as "what is driving sales".  Gosh, people don't even do a good job of this, so it is a lot to ask of unsupervised computers.

It is not clear to me that the data even contains the answer to the question.  The data does contain descriptions of what has sold and various other factors.  Whether these "drive" sales is rather subjective.

Others have given valuable suggestions on programming tools.  I would strongly suggest that you focus at data mining tools instead of programming tools.  SQL Server does have a tool built-in.  I'm not sure if that helps.  You can find a list of tools [here](http://www.kdnuggets.com/).  Some of these are freeware.  If you access them through programming you will face two problems.  The first is that you will only focus on the "programming" side of the problem rather than the results.  The second is that even if you find good results, you won't be in a position to communicate them to others.

Finally, my guess on what they really want is a tool that can slice and dice the data along various dimensions -- also available in SQL Server.  You can put together a set of tables following a fact-table structure (as Ralph Kimball describes in his books such as "The Data Warehouse Toolkit").  This sounds like a reporting problem, not a machine learning problem.

Comment: thanks so much for your answer, gordon. i respectfully disagree with you regarding looking at the data across diff dimensions. this is not a linear problem. there are very many variables involved in the business and i would like to be able to grab a bunch of them and find some kind of patterns

Comment: Is the data organized as a fact table?  Extracting "dimensional" information from transactional records is going to take most of your effort.

Comment: Not sure how it went.. but I actually agree with @GordonLinoff.. fundamentally machine learning is an experiment. If you don't have enough features to create predictive models, regardless of how much data you have on the rest of the dimension.. or use Google/Azure/SQL server.. predictions are going to be not accurate..